# Removing "cm" unit from column in R with a catch

Tags: r

I have a Height column here in RStudio that contains *character* strings (eg 188cm) as well as a few entries that are in feet and inches (eg 5'11")! Dirty dirty data..

My question is this: How do I remove the "cm" unit from the column as well as convert the feet/inches rows to the numeric cm value I need to keep the column consistent? I would like the entire column to have values in cm (eg 188) strictly. Thank you for your time! I am a beginner data analyst and have already completed one case study on my own however this seemingly simple task eludes me. Bear in mind that I have 18,979 entries so I would need a code that addresses the entire column. Thank you!

I used:

```
gsub("cm","",paste(fifa21_v2$Height))
```

and that produced a table that removed the "cm" (great news)
but then I noticed the feet/inches variables that then appeared as "6'0"" (not good)

```
dput(fifa21_v2$Height[820:875])
    c("195cm", "179cm", "191cm", "170cm", "182cm", "195cm", "178cm", 
    "187cm", "187cm", "190cm", "188cm", "198cm", "180cm", "172cm", 
    "189cm", "192cm", "179cm", "184cm", "186cm", "178cm", "173cm", 
    "176cm", "173cm", "187cm", "182cm", "186cm", "188cm", "170cm", 
    "6'3\"", "6'5\"", "185cm", "179cm", "195cm", "179cm", "185cm", 
    "174cm", "183cm", "180cm", "181cm", "186cm", "178cm", "5'11\"", 
    "6'4\"", "6'1\"", "6'0\"", "6'1\"", "5'11\"", "6'2\"", "6'0\"", 
    "6'3\"", "6'0\"", "184cm", "5'10\"", "5'9\"", "5'11\"", "5'6\""
    )
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can provide sample data as code, e.g. by running `dput(fifa21_v2$Height[820:875])` and pasting the output into the body of your question.

Comment: I pasted the output. Hopefully this is what you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- data.frame(Height = c("195cm", "179cm", "191cm", "170cm", "182cm", "195cm", "178cm", 
  "187cm", "187cm", "190cm", "188cm", "198cm", "180cm", "172cm", 
  "189cm", "192cm", "179cm", "184cm", "186cm", "178cm", "173cm", 
  "176cm", "173cm", "187cm", "182cm", "186cm", "188cm", "170cm", 
  "6'3\"", "6'5\"", "185cm", "179cm", "195cm", "179cm", "185cm", 
  "174cm", "183cm", "180cm", "181cm", "186cm", "178cm", "5'11\"", 
  "6'4\"", "6'1\"", "6'0\"", "6'1\"", "5'11\"", "6'2\"", "6'0\"", 
  "6'3\"", "6'0\"", "184cm", "5'10\"", "5'9\"", "5'11\"", "5'6\""
))


library(tidyverse)
a |>
  # spit the Height column into two new columns separated by '
  separate(Height, c("Feet", "Inches"), sep = "'", remove = FALSE) |>
  # try to convert the columns from Feet to Inches into numeric
  mutate(across(Feet:Inches, ~parse_number(.x))) |>
  # if Inches is NA (b/c no ', presumably), use the first number, 
  #   otherwise convert from the Feet and Inches columns
  mutate(Height2 = if_else(is.na(Inches), Feet, 
                           round((Feet + Inches/12)*30.48)))
```

Result (excerpt)

```
   Height Feet Inches Height2
26  186cm  186     NA     186
27  188cm  188     NA     188
28  170cm  170     NA     170
29   6'3"    6      3     190
30   6'5"    6      5     196
31  185cm  185     NA     185
32  179cm  179     NA     179
33  195cm  195     NA     195
34  179cm  179     NA     179
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and time! I will work this into my console. I apologize if there was not enough information to work with. I am very new to this. You are the first person I have been able to formulate a question for regarding data analysis. So, thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for editing with raw data, that makes it easier to help. Edited to work with that sample of data.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I will work with this upon returning home. You are a saint. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Just an update: You rock. It worked. That is all.